# Finding the real solutions of the radical equation $\sqrt{3x+10}-\sqrt{x+2}=2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radical-equations

> Find the solutions to the following:$$\sqrt{3x+10}-\sqrt{x+2}=2$$

This is what I tried so far:
\begin{align*}
(\sqrt{3x+10}-\sqrt{x+2})^2 & =2\\
(3x+10)+(x+2)-2\sqrt{(x+2)(3x+10)} & =2\\
2x+5-\sqrt{3x^2+16x+20} & =0
\end{align*}

Now I do not know where to go from here...

Comment: I just thought I'd point out that your equation is not a polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$2x+5-\sqrt{3x^2+16x+20}=0\iff2x+5=\sqrt{3x^2+16x+20} \Longrightarrow\\(2x+5)^2=3x^2+16x+20.$

Answer (score 3):

Rather than squaring both sides as stated, it might be more useful to use
$$
\sqrt{3x+10}=2+\sqrt{x+2}
$$
which can then be squared to get
$$
3x+10 = 6+x+4\sqrt{x+2}
$$
You can probably finish it from here for yourself.